# xsd to java with underscore in xsd file

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

Consider the below xsd file:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="Customer_Info" type="Customer"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Customer_Info">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="Profile" type="Profile" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xsd:element name="Address" type="integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Profile">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="Name" minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Email" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Phone" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Address">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="FlatNo" minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
          <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Street" minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="Landmark" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

As you can see in this I Have '_' in the Customer_Info complex type. Now when I generate Java files using JAXB's xjc command I get file name as CustomerInfo.java.
Also I want to have the type of flatNo as String in my generated Java files

....whereas I desire to get the filename as Customer_Info.java. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an external binding file to keep the `_`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  version="2.1">
  <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When using `xjc` you can use the `-b` option to reference the binding file.

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

Comment: Can you help me on one more query which i have mentioned in the question?