# xsd enumeration start with number underscore

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb, xsd

using jaxb to generate java POJO sources from xsd definition. while defining simpleType:String, enumeration, if the value starts with an underscore or a number, the corresponding Enum class is not generated. how can i use a pattern or setting to allow generation of such enums.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="TrailerType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="_20FT"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="OTHR"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
```

to make this work i had to add a manual explicit binding as

```
<jxb:bindings  schemaLocation="common/v1/CommonTypes.xsd" node="//xs:simpleType[@name='TrailerType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='_20FT']">
    <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_20FT"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

now this works and enum with value _20FT is generated, but if i have many such enums, i will need to add many explicit bindings. am sure there is a simpler more generic way to handle such enum names. 
please help.

Comment: followed http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html for the temp fix.

Comment: Try the binding file from the linked answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308043/xsd-to-java-with-underscore-in-xsd-file/18311923#18311923

Comment: i tried this too, this adds further underscores to the enum. so _20FT becomes somehow _ _20FT and ABC_XYZ becomes ABC_ _ _XYZ.

Comment: Have you tried `<globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName"/>`?

Comment: Unfortunately, both options `<globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" underscoreBinding="asCharInWord" />` do not work together, when there is a `Enum` class with name containing `underscore` and the members also contains `underscores`. In such cases, 2nd approach is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

**First** by global binding as suggest @lexicore

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
  version="2.1">

      <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName"/>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

generated enum by `maven-jaxb2-plugin`

```
@XmlType(name = "TrailerType")
@XmlEnum
public enum TrailerType {

    @XmlEnumValue("_20FT")
    VALUE_1("_20FT"),
    @XmlEnumValue("OTHR")
    VALUE_2("OTHR");
    private final String value;

    TrailerType(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static TrailerType fromValue(String v) {
        for (TrailerType c: TrailerType.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

**Second** by simple binding as you said for each enum

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net">
    <bindings schemaLocation="pathOfYourXSD.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='TrailerType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='_20FT']">
            <typesafeEnumMember name="_20FT"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

generated enum by `maven-jaxb2-plugin`

```
@XmlType(name = "TrailerType")
@XmlEnum
public enum TrailerType {

    _20FT,
    OTHR;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static TrailerType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: used the following as an alternative to 2nd suggestion.
    <xsd:annotation>
   <xsd:appinfo>
    <jxb:typesafeEnumClass >
    <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_20FT" value="_20FT"/>
    <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_32FT" value="_32FT"/>
    <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_48FT" value="_48FT"/>
    <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="_53FT" value="_53FT"/>
    </jxb:typesafeEnumClass>
   </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>